# How to manipulate data in multi-dimensional lists?

Tags: python, list

I am trying to change one list of lists structure into this other list of lists using Python. For example, if I have the following list and I want to replace some of the inner contents with blank how can I do it. Below, I have provided a typical input and output for what I am asking for. And, this needs to be in Python.

Input:

```py
[[['1','2','3','X'], ['4','5','6','Y'], ['7','8','9','Z']],
 [['a','b','c'], ['d','e','f'], ['g','h','i']],
 [['a1','a2','a3'],['b1','b2','b3'],['c1','c2','c3']]]
```

Output:

```py
[[['1','','','X'], ['4','','','Y'], ['7','','','Z']],
 [['a','b','c'], ['d','e','f'], ['g','h','i']],
 [['a1','a2','a3'], ['b1','b2','b3'], ['c1','c2','c3']]]
```

Comment: Are you missing a comma in `['7','8','9''Z']` ? Between `'9'` and `'Z'`?

Comment: Revised. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is an interesting question. It's great that you included the input and desired output. However, I don't see how to relate the wording of your question to that input and output. What is Z? Is it a sheet identifier? Also, what code do you have already? Have you written any of the code which uses Revit yet?

Comment: Thanks Jim! This was just a sample to see if it's possible to find a code that is able to replace some of the contents or to manipulate data within sublists. Z is just a random string. I have some code but it's very basic and is getting input from Revit-Dynamo.

Comment: Then I'm sorry, I don't understand what you are asking. Are you asking how to use Revit to extract data from a spreadsheet into a Python list of lists? Are your asking how to use Python to change one list of lists into another list of lists? Or are you asking how to use Revit to insert data from a Python list of lists into a spreadsheet?

Comment: I was asking how to use Python to change one list of lists into another list of lists. Pandy helped me solve my problem.

Comment: Oh, I get it! On Stack Overflow, an important step to getting good answers is to ask clear questions. It seems to me that your entire first paragraph was not necessary to your question. It was even perhaps a distraction. You were really asking, "how can I change one list of lists structure into this other list of lists using Python". Revit, and sheet numbers, and so on, don't matter to this question. Hopefully your next question will be even better, and will produce even better answers.

Comment: Thank you very much Jim. You are right. I will revise my question based on the discussions here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest replacing sublists through a for loop,because in python
`array[:][1]` does not select the first element from each sybarray but selects the first subarray (just like `array[1]` does) for multidimensional arrays.

```
for i in range(len(arr)-1):
        for j in range(len(len(arr[i])):
              #replace with if statements
```

Comment: I applied your code to my problem and I got an error. In my actual problem I have IN[0][i][j][k] for all i from 0 to 5 and for all j from 10 to 30, k from 0 to 20 I need to catch data for k from 0 to 3 and from 7 to 10 and replace 4 to 6 with " " while maintaining i and j as is. Is this possible?

Comment: Of course it's possible. Write in your inner loop:   for k in range(4,7):IN[0][i][j][k]=" " That would apply for all i,j. If you want for specific i,j apply if statement before the inner loop

Answer (score 1):

Distilling this down, I think you are looking for the `list.pop` method to "get rid of some of the data and receive an output", and slicing to access a range of values. For example

```
>>> l = list(range(10))
>>> l
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> l.pop(5)
5
>>> l
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> l[3:6]
[3, 4, 6]
```

Update based on comment:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint as pp
>>> pp(l)
[[[1, 2, 3, 'a'], [4, 5, 6, 'b'], [7, 8, 9, 'c']],
 [[1, 2, 3, 'd'], [4, 5, 6, 'e'], [7, 8, 9, 'f']],
 [[1, 2, 3, 'g'], [4, 5, 6, 'h'], [7, 8, 9, 'i']]]
>>> for outer in l:
...   for inner in outer:
...     inner[1:3] = ["", ""]
>>> pp(l)
[[[1, '', '', 'a'], [4, '', '', 'b'], [7, '', '', 'c']],
 [[1, '', '', 'd'], [4, '', '', 'e'], [7, '', '', 'f']],
 [[1, '', '', 'g'], [4, '', '', 'h'], [7, '', '', 'i']]]
```

Comment: What if I need to remove 2, 6 and 9?

Comment: Do you want to remove by index or value?

Comment: It's much more complicated than what I am writing here but for the first step for example I would like to change [[[1,2,3,'a'],[4,5,6,'b'],[7,8,9,'c']],[[1,2,3,'d'],[4,5,6,'e'],[7,8,9,'f']],[[1,2,3,'g'],[4,5,6,'h'],[7,8,9,'i']]] to [[[1,"","",'a'],[4,"","",'b'],[7,"","",'c']],[[1,"","",'d'],[4,"","",'e'],[7,"","",'f']],[[1,"","",'g'],[4,"","",'h'],[7,"","",'i']]]

Comment: Updated answer with a new solution.

Comment: I applied your code to my problem and I got an error. In my actual problem I have IN[0][i][j][k] for all i from 0 to 5 and for all j from 10 to 30, k from 0 to 20 I need to catch data for k from 0 to 3 and from 7 to 10 while maintaining i and j as is.

Comment: Here is the error: Warning: IronPythonEvaluator.EvaluateIronPythonScript operation failed. 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 38, in <module>
TypeError: iteration over non-sequence of type NoneType

Comment: Please update you question with the most simplified code possible to reproduce your issue.